# What's the difference between "new Class" and "new Class()" in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
function ClassA(){
  this.value = 5;
}

var obj1 = new ClassA;
var obj2 = new ClassA();

console.log(obj1.value);
console.log(obj2.value);
```

Both prints '5' in the console. What's the difference between both the ways (other than the inclusion of arguments for the constructor)?

Comment: The answers you've got are correct, but if you're interested in the full details, this behaviour is documented [in the spec](http://es5.github.com/#x11.2.2).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The parentheses are optional - if you do not have any constructor parameters to pass, they can be omitted.

Strangely enough, semicolons are also (sometimes) optional thanks to Automatic Semicolon Insertion ([source](http://mislav.uniqpath.com/2010/05/semicolons/), [more](http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2011/2/6/automatic-semicolon-insertion/)). This sparked a lengthy debate earlier this year and prompted a response from [Douglas Crockford](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=3842713) (JSON/JSLint inventor, JS guru).

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any difference at all.

If there are no arguments, and there is a `new`, then the parentheses are optional.