# Difference between Class(), new Class and new Class()

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

What are the differences between `Class()` and `new Class`, `new Class()`? I did a test and the later seems to do be quicker.

http://jsperf.com/object-initilzation

I read there is no difference, but there appears to be.

Comment: Related question

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13376028/whats-the-difference-between-new-class-and-new-class-in-javascript

Comment: and what about `Class()`? Also there seems to be a performance difference?

Comment: Not entirely sure what you mean by that but if I am correct, I believe Javascript just assumes you are trying to call the constructor so it's similar to `new Class()`. I can't say for sure though so don't take my word for that.

Comment: The first one `Class()` has nothing to do here, I think you are confused there

Comment: See the jsperf link. There seems to be a serious difference between `Class()` and the others. All of them call the constructor.

Comment: @user1680104, only two of them returns an instance

Comment: Makes sense, but why does it call the constructor then?

Comment: Okay. I know what I didn't grasp. I shouldn't blindly take the output from CoffeeScript and ask questions before taking a closer look at it. Sorry for the noise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `Class()`

Calls a function. Don't use this on constructor functions.

> `new Class` and `new Class()`

There is no difference between these, both instantiate a new instance of a class. The parens are optional if there are no arguments being passed and the `new` keyword is used.

Answer (score 0):

`Class()` is a misuse of constructor function. When you call it like this, it has a global scope as the context object and it does not create the new instance of Class. I guess, that the main difference between `new Class` and `new Class()` is in some arguments optimization, used by certain javascript engined

Answer (score 0):

If you have a class like this:

```
function Test(propVal){
    this.prop = propVal;
}
```

You will get the next results:

**Calling Test()**
This will return "undefined" since Test is working as a constructor

**Calling new Test(5)**
You will get a new instance of Test and that instance will have its "prop" set to 5

**Calling new Test**
You will get a new instance of Test and that instance will have its "prop" set to undefined

I hope this helped.

Thanks,